# Script task not run after first loop in the loop container

Tags: ssis

Script task not run after first loop in the  loop container. 
Tried adjusting expression as well, same result.

Attached is the screenshot after first run:

[image]

Comment: The amount of information you're providing us is overwhelming. I just can't process it all. But really, share some more details.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to run it multiple times then you should use For Each Loop conatiner